# How to join 2 columns of similar data into a single column in a same excel file with same column headings using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this image i had 4 columns with repeated column names . i needed only 2 columns one for item and one for amount with all the values in only 2 columns.Can anyone please help me out .Thanks in advance.

[image: data sample]

Comment: is it a CSV file you are opening?

Answer (score 0):

If you can read 2 columns here, read 4 columns at a time. Access by their index. Assuming it's a CSV file,

```
import csv
rows = []
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, ...)
    for row in reader:
         item_amount1 = row[1:3]
         item_amount2 = row[3:5]
         rows.extend([item_amount1, item_amount2])
```

Comment: @bunnyroyal You need to provide more in information. Answer the question I asked you in the comment section of the question. Add a sample file. Add the code you wrote to solve it. Also add the error or output it shows that doesn't match as your expectation. Then I can update the answer.

Comment: Actually it is an excel sheet and I have converted it into CSV file  using df.to_csv and applied your code.There are no error and also no change in output .The output remains same as in the image.

Comment: The image is of an excel sheet. And the program works on the csv you created. You need to show the code that you are executing and the data file. Show me all of the code where you wrote `df.to_csv()`